# Should Chrome be deleting cookies when using an application shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

We've noticed what looks like strange behavior when using Chrome's application shortcut (Tools | Create application shortcuts). If you're visiting a site using the shortcut, and that site has cookies that expire with the session, opening and closing Chrome will delete those cookies. For us this is an issue because deleting those cookies effectively logs the user out of the application.

Steps to reproduce:
- Using an application shortcut, go to a site that has a cookie set to expire with the session
- Open up Chrome normally, then close it
- Notice that all session expiration cookies have been deleted

This does not happen if you visit the site using the browser as normal. Unsure whether this is a bug or not, hoping to work around it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Opening and closing Chrome should always delete all session cookies. If it doesn't, there's a bug.

> A user's session cookie (also known as an in-memory cookie or transient cookie) for a website exists in temporary memory only while the user is reading and navigating the website. When an expiry date or validity interval is not set at cookie creation time, a session cookie is created. Web browsers normally delete session cookies when the user closes the browser.

(From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie))

Comment: Right, maybe I wasn't clear in my question. Open up a site using an application shortcut. Then open a different instance of Chrome, and immediately close it (your application shortcut is still open). Any session cookies that belonged to the application shortcut are now gone.

Comment: That sounds more like a bug. However, it's easy to understand how that happens.